# SSAS Tabular View

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I am in the process of building my first tabular view and have a question.

The tabular model I have has 3 tables based on 3 views that exist on SQL server. An incident view, a users view and a category view.

On the incident view, I have 2 columns (AssignedUser,CreatedUser) which both can be linked to the users view based on user ID, however I have been told only one relationship between tables can be active at one time? If this is the case how would I link both assigned and created user back to the user table?

Sorry if it's simple to answer, I couldn't find anything helpful on google and I have tried!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need to join 2 times (or more) your Dimension User, you could **duplicate** your existing view. 
for example:
Your **DimUser** view will be  **DimUserInCharge** (Or DimSupportTeam, ..) and **DimEndUser** (or DimClient, ..)

*Here is a small exeample based on Adventure Works DB*
[image: Here is a small exeample based on Adventure Works DB]

If you want to keep the same dimension, you will have to design your Fact in a different way. (And maybe add another dimension like "DimUserType")
or Add 2 differents Fact table
...

Does it help you?
Arnaud